# CorePlot 2.0 legends

Tags: core-plot

I've installed CorePlot 2.0 in my mac application, and I've added a CPTLegend to my CPTXYGraph object but the legendTitleForPieChart method is never being called.  How do I specify the legend titles for each plot?

Obviously I've cut out most of the other code in this file.

```swift
import Cocoa
import CorePlot

class ReportYearProducerProductionViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet private weak var hostingView: CPTGraphHostingView!

    private func configureChart() {
        let pieChart = CPTPieChart()
        pieChart.dataSource = self

        hostingView.hostedGraph!.addPlot(pieChart)
    }
}

extension ReportYearProducerProductionViewController: CPTPieChartDataSource {
    func legendTitleForPieChart(pieChart: CPTPieChart, recordIndex idx: UInt) -> String? {
        return "Title \(idx)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the pie chart otherwise draw correctly (i.e., are the other datasource methods called)? I tried your `legendTitleForPieChart()` function verbatim in one of the example apps and it worked fine.

Comment: Yes, it's calling the other datasource methods, and the pie is drawing properly.

Comment: Is the legend visible? When do you create the legend and add it to the graph?

Comment: The legend just appears as a tiny white rectangle.  I create it in viewDidLoad.  You can see exactly what I'm doing at this gist:  https://gist.github.com/grosch/fe0ab76d2e06f0816e51

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating the legend before the graph has any plots. Since there are no plots associated with the legend, it doesn't know to ask the plot for the title.

Either create the legend (`CPTLegend(graph: graph)`) after adding the plots to the graph, or add the plots to both the graph and the legend when you create them.